# Simple event handlers in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to implement a simple event bus in scala. The buiding blocks are:

```
// an event type
trait Event

// an event handler
trait EventHandler[-T <: Event] {
  def handle(event: T)
}

// a map to register the event handlers
val eventRegistry =
  new Map[Class[_], EventHandler[_]]()
```

I have a function to register my event handlers:

```
def registerEventHandler[T: ClassTag](handler: EventHandler[T]) = {
  val key = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
  eventHandlers.put(key, handler)
}
```

I need a function to handle an event. The function can receive AnyRef and need to pick up the event hander from the map (if any exists) and handle the event.

```
def handle(msg:AnyRef) {
  // cast msg to an event. msg myght be or not an Event
  // obtain the correct event handle from the eventRegistry
  handler.handle(e)
}
```

Is there a way to do this in scala?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with messages that aren't events? As your comment says *"cast msg to an event"*.

Comment: Messages that are not subtypes of Event are just ignored.

Comment: You could take a look at the [source code of *slick-eventsourcing*](https://github.com/softwaremill/slick-eventsourcing/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/events/Registry.scala) by Adam Warski.

Comment: Then why not require a generic type parameter with a `<: Event` constraint instead of `AnyRef`?

Comment: @PeterNeyens -  thanks. it answered my quetions!

Comment: I have put up a small project implementing this https://github.com/hipjim/scala-event-bus